# Java code not running on hackerrank

Tags: java

```
Node Insert(Node head,int x) {
Node head_node = head;
while( head.next != null )
{
head = head.next;
}
Node new_node = null;
new_node.data = x;
head.next= new_node;
return head_node;
}
```

This is a piece of code that is supposed to take the head of a Linked List and add an element to the end of the linked list and then return the head of the updated linked list.

But it is giving a runtime error when I run it on hacker rank .

Can anyone please tell me the reason.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `new_node` is null and hence it would throw `NullPointerException`.
Initialise new Node to a Node object.

`Node new_node = new Node();`

Answer (score 0):

Your Node new_node is not initialized before you try to set its data. You would need to construct it first.

```
Node new_node = new Node();
new_node.data = x;
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare `new_node` as,

```
Node new_node = null;
```

So `new_node` is `null` object now. So if you try access `data` from a `null` object `new_node` writing this `new_node.data` then you will get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Replace

```
Node new_node = null;
```

With

```
Node new_node = new Node();
```